# Swift - local / server image isn't being loaded in HTML String for pdf

Tags: html, ios, swift, pdf

I'm creating pdf from HTML String. I added image tag with source (live Image URL and Local image path.) But in both ways not able to add image in pdf. Rest text data and tables are working but image doesn't load. here is my source to create HTML String and to create PDF.

```
extension EstimationVC{
var htmlString: String {
    //let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "logo", ofType: "png")!
    var baseStringStart = "<table style=\"height: 20px;\" width=\"100%; padding: 10px;\">   <tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 30px;\">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody>    <tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 100%; text-align: left;\"><h1>From:  \(params["senderCompany"] as? String ?? "") </h1></td></tr></tbody>                         <tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 100px; height:100px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: left;\"><img src=\"logo.png\"/></td></tr></tbody>                         <tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 100%; text-align: right;\">Preventivo #: \(params["invoiceNo"] as? String ?? "")</td></tr></tbody>    <tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 100%; text-align: right;\">Op. Name: \(params["operatorName"] as? String ?? "")</td></tr></tbody>   <tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 100%; text-align: right;\">Date: \(currentDate)</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 100%; text-align: center;\"><strong>\(params["companyName"] as? String ?? "")</strong></td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 100%; text-align: center;\">\(params["countryOrRegion"] as? String ?? "")</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>          <table style=\"height: 20px; background: #fff;\" width=\"100%;\"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>           <table border=\"1\" width=\"100%\" frame=\"hsides\" rules=\"rows\"><tbody style=\"border: 1px solid black;\"><tr style=\"background: #eee; color: #000;\"><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"10%\">&nbsp;Code</td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"40%\">&nbsp;Description</td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"10%\">&nbsp;U.M.</td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"10%\">&nbsp;Unit Price</td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"10%\">&nbsp;Quantity</td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"20%\">&nbsp;Price Without Vat</td></tr></tbody>"
    let rowString = "<tbody><tr><td style=\"padding: 5px;\" width=\"10%\">&nbsp;{code}</td></td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: left;\" width=\"40%\">{description}&nbsp;</td></td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"10%\">{um}&nbsp;</td></td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"10%\">{unit_price}&nbsp;</td></td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"10%\">{quantity}&nbsp;</td></td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"20%\">{price_without_vat}&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody>"
    
    for description in selectedDataArr.enumerated(){
        var temp = rowString.replacingOccurrences(of: "{code}", with: selectedCodesArr[description.offset].1)
        temp = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "{description}", with: description.element.1)
        temp = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "{um}", with: selectedUMArr[description.offset].1)
        temp = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "{unit_price}", with: selectedPriceArr[description.offset].1)
        temp = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "{quantity}", with: String(quantityArr[description.offset]))
        temp = temp.replacingOccurrences(of: "{price_without_vat}", with: String(priceWithoutVatArr[description.offset]))

        baseStringStart.append(temp)
    }
    let baseStringEnd = "</table><table width=\"100%\"><tbody style=\"><tr style=\"color: #000;\"><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: right;\" width=\"80%\">&nbsp;<strong>Price Without VAT:</strong> </td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"20%\">&nbsp;<strong>\(priceWithoutVatArr.sum())</strong></td></tr>           <tr style=\"color: #000;\"><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: right;\" width=\"80%\">&nbsp;<strong>VAT(%): </strong> </td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"20%\">&nbsp;<strong>\(params["vat"] as? String ?? "")</strong></td></tr>        <tr style=\"color: #000;\"><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: right;\" width=\"80%\">&nbsp;<strong>Total Price:</strong> </td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"20%\">&nbsp;<strong>\(totalPriceWithVAT)</strong></td></tr>    <tr style=\"color: #000;\"><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: right;\" width=\"80%\">&nbsp;<strong></strong> </td><td style=\"padding: 5px; text-align: center;\" width=\"20%\">&nbsp;<strong></strong></td></tr>     </tbody></table>"
    
    return baseStringStart + baseStringEnd
    
}

}
```

Here is My Function to create PDF.

```
func createPDF(_ completion:  @escaping(_ fileCreated: Bool)-> ()) {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")!
    var HTMLContent = try? String(contentsOfFile: path)

    print(HTMLContent!)
    HTMLContent = HTMLContent?.replacingOccurrences(of: "#bodyData#", with: htmlMainString!)
    
    
    
    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: HTMLContent!)
    // 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer
    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)

    // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect
    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, .zero, nil)
    
    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    // 5. Save PDF file
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

    
        pdfData.write(toFile: "\(documentsPath)/file.pdf", atomically: true)
        completion(true)
    
}
```

Actually this line of code has some error. I tried to add live image url here but this doesn't work.

```
   <tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 100px; height:100px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: left;\"><img src=\"logo.png\"/></td></tr></tbody>
```

any solution to handle Image logo in PDF. here is my outcome without Logo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's another technique.

First, load your html string in a `WKWebView`. Then get `viewPrintFormatter()` of your webview and add that view to your `UIPrintPageRenderer()`.
Not tested yet, but in my mind, all images should be rendered before printing, so it should work.

```
let formatter = yourWebView.viewPrintFormatter()
let printPageRenderer = UIPrintPageRenderer()
printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(formatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)
```

Details is here https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/create-pdf-from-uiview-wkwebview-and-uitableview/

Comment: Thank You, well how to adjust that image tag in html string?

Comment: you mean css and style attribute?

Comment: Yes. You mean I need to load my htmlString to WKWebview. Then next procedure to UIPrintPageRenderer(),  but    <tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 100px; height:100px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: left;\"><img src=\"logo.png\"/></td></tr></tbody>  
 this doesn't even display an image in webview

Comment: where do you save your `logo.png`, is it a remote or local image? please try with random remote image url first, then do it with absolute local path.

Comment: Yeah did the same with URL image also..not worked